# Redux saga test case - jest.spyOn

Tags: jestjs, redux-saga

I am getting undefined as response for a mocked api call using jest.spyOn() and mockImplmentation.

> Saga.tsx

```
export function* parseUserData(parsingAction: IParsingAction) {

try {
    const skills = yield call(SkillRepository.getAllSkills);

    console.log('------skils-----', skills);    // undefined

    const industries = yield call(IndustryRepository.getAllIndustry);

    if (skills.skillGroup && industry.industryGroup) 
      {

        yield put(getSkillsSuccess(skills.skillGroups));
        yield put(getIndustriesSuccess(industry.industryGroups));

      } 

    else 
   {
       yield put(bulkUploadError());
   }

    } catch (error) {

    yield put(bulkUploadError());

}
```

}

> Saga.test.tsx

```
describe('ParseUserData job saga', () => {
const action = {
    type: bulkUploadActionType.GET_API_DATA,
    payload: {
        sheetData: {},
        isAdvisor: true,
    },
};
const generator = parseUserData(action);
it('Should call skill repository', () => {
    const skills = { skillGroups: [] };
    const spy = jest.spyOn(SkillRepository, 'getAllSkills');
    spy.mockImplementation((): any => {
        return (skills);
    });
    expect(generator.next().value).toEqual(call(SkillRepository.getAllSkills));
    spy.mockRestore();
});
```

});

Any help would be appreciated. Its very simple thing but I am stuck with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When testing sagas as pure generators, the redux saga middleware is not hooked up to drive the generator - you must do that yourself. So `SkillRepository.getAllSkills` is not actually called, instead you need to supply the expected value to `generator.next()`. You can see this in the first example of the Testing section where `gen.next(chooseColor(color))` is called to drive the generator. In your case you'd do something like:

```
expect(generator.next().value).toEqual(call(SkillRepository.getAllSkills));
expect(generator.next(skills).done).toBe(true);
```

Since it's the redux saga middleware that is actually executing the `call` effect, if you want to test that `SkillRepository.getAllSkill` is called when your saga is run you'll need to follow the example under `Testing the full Saga` where `runSaga` is used to have `redux-saga` drive the generator, and where you can mock/spy on modules to see if they're called.

So I would re-write your test as:

```
it('Should call skill repository', () => {
    const skills = { skillGroups: [] };
    const spy = jest.spyOn(SkillRepository, 'getAllSkills');
    spy.mockImplementation((): any => {
        return (skills);
    });
    runSaga(
      {dispatch: () => {}, getState: () => ({})}, // flesh these out if need be
      parseUserData, action
    ).toPromise().then(() => {
      expect(SkillRepository.getAllSkills.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
      spy.mockRestore();
    )
});
```

EDIT

For the unit test with the full saga as shared above:

```
describe('ParseUserData job saga', () => {
const action = {
    type: bulkUploadActionType.GET_API_DATA,
    payload: {
        sheetData: {},
        isAdvisor: true,
    },
};
const generator = parseUserData(action);
it('Should call skill repository', () => {
    const skills = { skillGroups: [] };
    const industries = { industryGroups: [] };

    expect(generator.next().value).toEqual(
      call(SkillRepository.getAllSkills));
    expect(generator.next(skills).value).toEqual(
      call(IndustryRepository.getAllIndustry));
    expect(generator.next(industries).value).toEqual(
      put(getSkillsSuccess(skills.skillGroups)));
    expect(generator.next().value).toEqual(
      put(getIndustriesSuccess(industries.industryGroups))
    );
    expect(generator.next().done).toBe(true);

});
```

Comment: But I am receiving false when i expect this.
```expect(generator.next(skills).done).toBe(true);```
Received false.
But yes I am getting the skills on saga now but test case is failing.

Comment: Is the `parseUserData` code you posted above the full saga? If there are more effects that you didn't include then the data won't be done yet. I imagine you're doing something with the result of `getAllSkills`.

Comment: Yes I am using the result. I have updated the saga please see.

Comment: Updated at the bottom of my post. Looks like your `parseUserData` generator has some typos though - should be `skills.skillGroups` and `industry.industryGroups` in the `if` statement before putting the successful actions.